# clicking checkbox doesn't change it

Tags: html, reactjs

I tried to use handleChange method to change the **completed** boolean who is responsible for checking the box but it does not change .. I can't find where it's missed up

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            todos: todosData
        }
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    }
    
    handleChange(id) {
        this.setState((prevState) => {
            const updatedTodos = prevState.todos.map(todo => {
                if (todo.id === id) {
                    todo.completed = !todo.completed
                }
                return todo
            })
            return {
                todos: updatedTodos
            }
        })
        
    }
    
    render() {
        const todoItems = this.state.todos.map(item => <TodoItem key={item.id} item={item} handleChange={this.handleChange}/>)
        
        return (
            <div className="todo-list">
                {todoItems}
            </div>
        )    
    }
}

export default App
```

and this is my ToDoItem component

```
function TodoItem(props) {
    return (
        <div className="todo-item">
            <input 
                type="checkbox" 
                checked={props.item.completed} 
                onChange={() => props.handleChange(props.item.id)}
            />
            <p>{props.item.text}</p>
        </div>
    )
}

export default TodoItem
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

You are mutating your state objects. When you don't return new object references React doesn't consider the value to be different and bails on rerendering with updated values.

```
if (todo.id === id) {
  todo.completed = !todo.completed // <-- state mutation!
}
return todo // <-- same todo object reference
```

## Solution

You need to also shallow copy any nested state you are updating.

```
handleChange(id) {
  this.setState((prevState) => ({
    todos: prevState.todos.map(todo => todo.id === id ? {
      ...todo, // <-- shallow copy todo
      completed: !todo.completed, // <-- update completed property
    } : todo)
  });
}
```